# how to move google email acct to new phone

Tags: gmail

I just got an HTC DNA (old phone is HTC Incredible). I need to move my gmail acct to new phone. I then need to remove a new gmail acct I created in error. Thanks, Jim.

Comment: Remove the new account from which device?

Comment: You add your Google Account to your new phone. When you're satisfied that all your old data is there, you factory reset the old phone. What, _specifically_, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

As Al Everett said, the best way would be to just sync your new phone with you Google account. But before you do that, make sure you:

- Make sure all contacts in contact book are synced to Google, not backup assistant or internal storage.
- Make sure all bookmarks or other web data are synced (if you use Google Chrome on Android)
- Make sure all of your Pictures and Videos are stored on your SD card, and not on your internal storage.

Optional: you could create a backup of your phone just in case if you need any of your data back. It's better to backup before and not use the backup than do it and need a backup and not have one. Just a thought.

Once you have everything synced to Google, then you are all set to sync your new phone with your Google account and factory reset your old phone.

> Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset -> Yes, I'm sure -> Yes absolutely sure -> ...

Good luck with the new device!